# LINQ left join + default if empty + anonymous type + group by

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, nullreferenceexception, anonymous-class

I wonder what is the best solution for the given problem, simplified here:

1. I have two locally stored sql tables which I want to join (left join) with Default If Empty property, then I need to group these data
2. I don't want to check for (obj == null) before accessing obj.column, which will throw an error if join was no successful for a given row

Data

```
LeftTable    RightTable    OUTPUT
 A B C        A B Z         A  B  C  Z
 1 1 1        1 1 5         1  1  1  5
 1 2 2        1 2 6         1  2  2  6
 5 6 7                      5  6  7 null
```

Code

```
var RightTable = from row in Source
                 where row.X > 10
                 select new {        // anonymous type that I want to keep
                    A = row.AAA,
                    B = row.BBB,
                    Z = row.ZZZ
                 };

var test = from left in LeftTable
           from right in RightTable
             .Where(right => right.A == left.A
                && right.B == left.B )
             .DefaultIfEmpty( /* XXXXX */ )   //<-- this line is interesting
           group left by new {
             left.A
             left.B
             left.C
             right.Z  //<-- this will throw null exception error
           } into g     //  but I don't want to change it to 
           select g;    //  Z = (right != null) ? right.Z : (string) null
```

Question:

Can I fill an argument in DefaultIfEmpty with anything that I can dynamically get from this code?

I know I can create a helper type like below and replace the anonymous type in RightTable select and use it inside default if empty like:

```
DefaultIfEmpty(new Helper())
```

but I dont want to do it as I have to deal with 20,30+ columns in real life scenario.

```
public class Helper {
    public string A,
    public string B,
    public string C
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time if you read until here. Hope to get some solution here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i think the `code` says everything:

```
var LeftTable = new[]
        {
            new { A = 1, B=1, C=1 },
            new { A = 1, B=2, C=2 },
            new { A = 5, B=6, C=7 }
        }
        .ToList();


        var RightTable = new[]
        {
            new { A = 1, B=1, Z=5 },
            new { A = 1, B=2, Z=6 }
        }
        .ToList();


        var query = (from left in LeftTable
                     join right in RightTable
                        on new { left.A, left.B } equals new { right.A, right.B }
                        into JoinedList
                     from right in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty(new { A = 0, B = 0, Z = 0 })
                     group left by new
                     {
                         left.A,
                         left.B,
                         left.C,
                         right.Z
                     } into g
                     select g)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks for your reply, it would work... however.. my big query joins about 10 tables with left joins and each one has anything up to 30 columns, I also use SQL to LINQ to get my sources before I use them, so ideally I would not redefine source structure inside the join.

Comment: ok, there is not any problem, you can use `.DefaultIfEmpty(new { A = 0, B = 0, Z = 0 })`, instead of yours `.DefaultIfEmpty( /* XXXXX */ )`

Comment: but surely, you need to pass something anonymous like your structure is to `.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: I ended up defining the structure that is left-joined (Right table) and then can reuse it inside .DefaultIfEmpy

Comment: I also tried Activator.CreateInstance but no luck with anonymous types.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, I had to find a way, came up to something like this (very simplified example):

```
var toReturn = from left in bd.leftys
               join rights in myAnonimousGroupedList on left.Id equals rights.leftId into joinings
               from right in joinings.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new {
                   left.A
                   left.B
                   left.C
                   // Z = right != null ? right.Z : 0
                   Z = joinings.Any() ? right.Z : 0 // see what i did here?
               };
```